# Values of cubic function

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, algebraic-number-theory

> Given $f(x)$ is a cubic polynomial such that $f(4)=16, f(3)=3, f(2)=2$ and $f(1)=1$ . I need to find the values of f(0),f(-1) and f(5)?

**My attempt**

It would be easy to assume the function to be

> $f(x)=a(x-p)(x-q)(x-r)$ *where $p,q,r$ are roots of the polynomial*

Now we would have four equations and four variables and it would be solvable.
However solving the four equations would be quite tedious.

I was wondering if there was an alternate way to compute 
the values of $f(0),f(-1)$ and $f(5)$ *without actually deducing the polynomial* ?

Answer (score 1):

We can not assume that there are three real roots. There is at least one, but it can be only one (this is the case for e.g. $x^3+x+1$). So, your attempt is wrong from the beginning.

The fastest way (with determining a polynomial) is Newton's Interpolation Formula. After 30 seconds of computiation I have found $$f(x)=1+(x-1)+2(x-1)(x-2)(x-3).$$

Of course, there is more elementary way. Denote $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$. This, together with interpolation conditions, produces a system of 4 linear equations, which has the unique solution. This is not difficult and rather short to solve it.

I will think whether or not, there is a need to find an interpolation polynomial.

Comment: How did you compute it in thirty seconds? What was your thought ?

Comment: The trick is to use Newton's triangle diagram. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial See the Examples part. As I said before, this is really fast method of polynomial interpolation.